# Show changes between consecutive lines of a file

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, grep

Is there an easy way to see how lines are changing in a file?
For example, assume I have this "my.log" file:

```
cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4
   5    3    3    6
   5    3    3    6
   5    0    3    6
   3    0    6    6
   5    3    3    0
```

From the command line, I want to enter something like "cat my.log | showchanges" and then see something like this:

```
cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4
   5    3    3    6
   "    "    "    "
   "    0    "    "
   3    "    6    "
   5    3    3    0
```

Ideally, "showchanges" would greedily treat any stretch of whitespace as a column separator to do this, but I am very flexible on the details.  I just want to easily see a change when there are many columns.  Also, it would eventually be nice to omit lines where there are no changes at all.

Comment: Assuming you can write programs: You need two arrays, one for the previous columns, one for the current columns. The compare the columns, possibly updating them. You could use `awk` for that. Remember: This is *not* a code writing service here.

Comment: @U.Windl Ok, I'll assume there is nothing then that a Unix/sed expert just executes on the fly.  I know a program could get it done, but I was hoping for something even easier since it basically just needs a 2-line stream editor.  With all of the power of perl, I'd still be surprised if there's not a short one-liner...

Comment: The real-time monitoring utility [`pw` (Pipe Watch)](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/) can highlight, in reverse video, the characters which change between successive snapshots.  I think this is seen in [this video](https://vimeo.com/710155314).

Comment: It'd be trivial, concise, efficient, and portable with awk but [as @U.Windl mentions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714080/show-changes-between-consecutive-lines-of-a-file#comment1352692_714080), this isn't a code writing service, it's a place where you can ask for help with YOUR code so if you post your attempt to solve the problem yourself I'm sure you'll get answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ bak=$0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)$i=($i==tmp[i]?"-":$i)
       split(bak, tmp)
}1' infile

cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4
5 3 3 6
- - - -
- 0 - -
3 - 6 -
5 3 3 0
```

---

To keep the records indentation (fields width of 4):

```
awk '{ bak=$0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)$i=sprintf("%4s", ($i==tmp[i]?"-":$i))
       split(bak, tmp)
}1' infile

cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4
   5    3    3    6
   -    -    -    -
   -    0    -    -
   3    -    6    -
   5    3    3    0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true: this is not a code writing service. But if a task is easy or fun, some of us act as one. (-;

Assuming you can't write programs, you still can use `sed`, no real one-liner with such a line length:

```
sed -E -e '1h;1n;H;x;s/$|\n/_&/g;:1' -e 's/( +)([^ ]+)_(.*)\1\2_/_\1\2\3_\1"/;t1' -e '/^_/!s/( +[^ ]+)_/_\1/g;/^_/!b1' -e 's/.*_//'
```

I did add a whitespace to the beginning of the first line to make the file consistent (other lines start with a whitespace, too). The idea is to keep the old line in old space and process a pair of the lines, using an underscore (use a different marker if the underscore can be part of your file) as marker where to check for identical records.

*Note: I'm afraid this is not really standard, because back references are not defined in extended regular expressions, but writing this with basic regular expressions looks really messy. I don't know of any `sed` version which doesn't support back references in ERE anyhow.*

Let's write it more readable:

```
sed -E '1h;1n;# handle the first line
  H;x;# add current line to hold space and exchange buffers to store the current line
  s/$|\n/_&/g;# now add the underscore add the end of the lines
  :1
  s/( +)([^ ]+)_(.*)\1\2_/_\1\2\3_\1"/;# if the record at the _ is repeated in the new line, replace it with a quote, advance the _ and repeat
  t1
  /^_/!s/( +[^ ]+)_/_\1/g;# the t did not loop, so if we are not the done, advance the _ and process if necessary
  /^_/!b1
  s/.*_//;# finally remove everything before the processed line'
```

Comment: That indeed worked, thank you.  Of course, it's a little longer and conceptually more complicated than I was hoping for.  Since I don't need to replace the repeats with a quote and I don't really need horizontal alignment (so repeats with their whitespace could just be deleted), maybe there is a much simpler trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
watch -d tail my.log
(default parameters, equivalent to : watch -d -n 2 tail -n 10 my.log)

watch -d -n 5 tail -n 15 my.log
At 5 seconds interval, watch last 15 lines from my.log

man watch
   -d, --differences [permanent]
          Highlight  the differences between successive updates.  
          Option will read optional argument that changes highlight to be permanent, 
          allowing to see what has changed at least once since first iteration.

   -n, --interval seconds
          Specify  update interval.  
          The command will not allow quicker than 0.1 second interval,
          in which the smaller values are converted. 
          Both '.' and ',' work for any locales.

man tail
   -n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; 
          or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

Comment: I ran watch as you suggested, but my version does not seem to support the "-d" option.  Anyway, I really want to look through days of logs retroactively and not watch constantly for changes, so this is not the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example with a bash script. I called it myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
LINEAS=$(cat "$FILENAME" | wc -l)
N=1
while read LINE
do
if [[ $N -gt 1 ]]; then
    if [[ $N -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo $LINE
        PREVIA=$LINE
    else
        L1=$(echo "$LINE" |awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
        L2=$(echo "$LINE" |awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
        L3=$(echo "$LINE" |awk -F' ' '{print $3}')
        L4=$(echo "$LINE" |awk -F' ' '{print $4}')
        P1=$(echo "$PREVIA" |awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
        P2=$(echo "$PREVIA" |awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
        P3=$(echo "$PREVIA" |awk -F' ' '{print $3}')
        P4=$(echo "$PREVIA" |awk -F' ' '{print $4}')
        if [[ $L1 -eq $P1 ]]; then
            R1="-"
        else
            R1="$L1"
        fi
        if [[ $L2 -eq $P2 ]]; then
            R2="-"
        else
            R2="$L2"
        fi
        if [[ $L3 -eq $P3 ]]; then
            R3="-"
        else
            R3="$L3"
        fi
        if [[ $L4 -eq $P4 ]]; then
            R4="-"
        else
            R4="$L4"
        fi
        echo $R1" "$R2" "$R3" "$R4
        PREVIA=$LINE
    fi
fi
let "N=N+1"
done < $FILENAME
```

Wnen execute the script

```
./myscript.sh my.log
```

The result is:

```
5 3 3 6
- - - -
- 0 - -
3 - 6 -
```

Comment: It's nice of you to write a full custom code for me, but I was more looking for standard Unix tools that almost get my job done when given the right options.  Anyway, I'd like it to work no matter how many columns there are (not just 4) and even if the number of columns changed halfway into the log file for some reason.